# How to create adjacency list from list of edges

Tags: python, graph

We want to write a function to separate a given workflow’s steps into multiple stages in such a way that all the steps in each individual stage can run at the same time. The function should return a list of lists, in which each list represents one stage. Each step should run in the earliest possible stage.

```
precursor_steps = [
  ["clean", "build"],
  ["metadata", "binary"],
  ["build", "link"],
  ["link", "binary"],
  ["clean", "metadata"],
  ["build", "resources"]
]
[
  ["clean"],
  ["build", "metadata"],
  ["resources", "link"],
  ["binary"]
]
```

I am trying to create adjacency list for the above graph but being new at Python I am not able to to do it.

Below code of mine works fine when the edges are integer but i am not able to use it for string edges

```
precursor_steps = [["clean", "build"],["metadata", "binary"],["build", "link"],["link", "binary"],["clean", "metadata"],
  ["build", "resources"]] 

#precursor_steps=[[0,1],[1,2],[2,1]]
def rungraph(nums):
    v = 0
    counter = set()
    for src, dest in nums:
        counter.add(src)
        counter.add(dest)
    #print counter
    v = len(counter)
    adj = {s:[] for s in range(v)}
    for p1, p2 in nums:
        print "p1",p1,"p2",p2
        adj[p1] += [p2]
    print "mtx=>",adj

rungraph(precursor_steps)
```

Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your declaration of `adj`. You want this dictionary to map each vertex to the list of vertices it is adjacent to. But you are initializing `adj` with numbers as keys (so when your input graph has `n` vertices, you are initializing `adj` to hold the numbers `0` to `n-1` as keys, each being mapped to the empty list). This works when your vertices are also numbers, as in your commented-out example. But it fails when your nodes are strings, because then the dictionary is initialized with numbers, so updating the value with the statement `adj[p1] += [p2]` fails, because the string `p1` is not present as the key in the dictionary.

To fix this, change the initialization of `adj` to:

```
adj = {s: [] for s in counter}
```